# Rounded mesh from an SVG

Tags: svg, smooth, remesh

I would like to achieve a result like this reference image.
I have the svg to work with, but I am not able to make it smoothly rounded like the reference. Bevel does not work properly, if I remesh it does not work either.
Manually drawing curves is not precise, how would you go about?

[image]

Comment: could you show the svg you're starting from?

Comment: Hello, please share your svg (use workupload for example)

Comment: You could easily do it from scratch, starting with curves

Comment: Please don't upload your file to a site that asks for permission to process your personal data! Use the official site at https://blend-exchange.com/ if the file is under 30Meg in size or somewhere like https://wetransfer.com/.

Comment: there you go https://we.tl/t-VBHxChBgEe

Comment: This is a full 3D shape, I'm not sure having an SVG is productive.

Comment: Hi :). The ScG is a stylized graphic translation. You'd have a much easier time modeling it from scratch, using the illustration as a guide :).

Answer (score 1):

Your svg won't help a lot, you should redo the shape from scratch, begin with a circle curve, cut a segment, fill, etc, in order to get this shape:

[image]

[image]

Then in the *Data panel > Shape >* increase the *Resolution*, and under *Geometry > Bevel* increase the *Depth*:

[image]

If necessary at the end you can right click and convert to mesh.

File: [image]

Comment: Very helpful, could you share blend file?

Comment: Sure, here it is: https://blend-exchange.com/b/eOn5gD4O